# how can i add css class on current page in wordpress wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation

how can i add css class on current page in wordpress wp_nav_menu

**For Example I Want To Use It In Wordpress wp_nav_menu**

```
<li><a href="index.php?id=index&colortheme=green" class="selected" title="Home">Home</a></li>
```

**Wordpress Code**

```
<?php $menu_args = array('menu' => 'Header' ); wp_nav_menu( $menu_args ); ?>
```

**Using This Function**

```
function add_nav_class($output) {
$output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="selected"', $output, 1);
return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

**but this function select only home and not highlight current page item thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

WordPress already adds a class for this purpose called `.current-menu-item` so just target this class in your css file.

For example, if your menu is in a div with an ID of `navigation`, add this:

```
#navigation .current-menu-item {}
```